# download from Firebase storage using qr codes

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, qr-code

Haven't started development yet, but I just want to ask if there would be some security issues if I created a qr code that will directly download something from the firebase storage, will there be some authorization stuff needed? still choosing wether to store it from google drive or firebase storage(payment capacity reasons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encode the download URL from Firebase Storage into the QR code, then anyone with the QR code can read the file. That is because the download URLs from Firebase Storage are publicly readable, but unguessable.

If you instead encode the path to the file into the QR code, then that file can only be access by a user that is signed in to Firebase and for whom the security rules you have configured allow read access to the file.

From what you described you're looking to use the first option with download URLs. It's hard to say what security issue you're asking about, but just be aware that in that case anyone with the QR code will know the download URL, and can thus read the file (or share that URL with others, so that they too can read the file). If that is not what you want, you'll need a more advanced scheme, which typically starts with being able to identify your users.

Comment: thanks! that answered my question, .getDownloadUrl() is all i need.